# TextBox LostFocus-Event always raised before Button Click-Event in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I've got the following scenario. A user enters a quantity in a TextBox and hits a Button to submit. The TextBox updates its ViewModel on "LostFocus" and the Button executes a Command on click. To make things more complicated, both events trigger async operations which are synchronized via SemaphoreSlim (Data should be updated on LostFocus before the command executes). In very few cases i suspect that the Clicked-Event is raised before LostFocus. Is that even possible? I wonder if it's guaranteed that the FocusLost event is always raised before the button clicked event in this scenario?

Comment: Why is updating OnLostFocus a requirement? The easiest solution is to set binding trigger to PropertyChanged

Comment: I'm not updating on LostFocus by my own code behind. The control is bound via compiled binding to it's view model. The update on LostFocus ist default behaviour that's why i mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to tests, *LostFocus* is being fired before *Clicked* event, however as it's async there is a chance that *Clicked* is being processed before *LostEvent* finished. If you want to ensure about the order, you may use some synchronization objects, like for example [async version of AutoResetEvent](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/11/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-2-asyncautoresetevent/). A sample can look like this:

```
AsyncAutoResetEvent resetEvent = new AsyncAutoResetEvent();

private async void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Starting lost focus");
    await Task.Delay(3000);
    resetEvent.Set();
    Debug.WriteLine("Leaving lost focus");
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Clicking button");
    await resetEvent.WaitAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine("Finishing with click event");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to check that later. At first glance it seems that your way of synchronizing is similar to mine. I've never heard of AsyncAutoResetEvent before but i'm going to check that as well.

Comment: I think you are right and LostFocus is alway raised before Clicked in my scenario. There must be another reason for the problems we encountered.